# Split pending orders into two teams

Tags: php, mysql, database, e-commerce

When the customers submit the orders on the website.. staffs can view the pending orders (pull data from mysql) on the admin backend but I want the pending orders to split into two team.

**Example**

We have received 21 pending orders.

There are 11 staffs.

**Team 1**: 5 staffs

**Team 2**: 6 staffs

*Team 1* can view 11 orders and *Team 2* can view 10

Sometime I might get 100 orders every hour - PHP should determine to split half of the pending orders into two teams (dynamically)...

Should the team_id set on the order table? Eg: `tbl_orders.team_id = 2` when users submit the orders? .. but what if not enough staffs logged in team 1 or 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways.

### First (dynamic)

First of all you count all the pendings:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pending;
```

Then you show the first half to team 1:

```
$half = round($count/2);
SELECT * FROM pending ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $half;
```

Team 2 gets:

```
SELECT * FROM pending ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $half,$half;
```

If you have more team you just need to divide for the total number of teams insted by 2.

### Second option (fixed)

When pending are inserted you associate them with a team. But you have to add another field to your table.

Let's say you have a field `team TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED`.

When the next pending is placed you check the last team inserted with this:

```
 SELECT team FROM pending ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Let's say you have a config where is stored your number of teams:

```
 $totalTeamsAvailable = 2;
```

With the value that you have select with the query you do:

```
 $nextTeam = (++$teamFromSql % $TotalTeamsAvailable) + 1;
```

Now you have the team that can be associated with this pending. Of course you add it with

```
 INSERT INTO pending (data,team) VALUES (,$nextTeam);
```

This second solution may suffer of race condition. (IE: 2 pending placed at nearly the same istant may be associated with the same team, but I believe this will not hurt at all )

## Addedum

To count the team that recently have done something you have 2 ways:

- You need a table `teams` where you store the last login data of the staff.
- Store each actions that each teams have done (for example team 1 approved and sent order pending #2) with a data (maybe you have already this table)

At this point it's easy to select the number of team with a recently activity.
Using the table team you just need to do a:

```
$teamWithRecentlyActivity = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teams WHERE lastLogin > (time() - (60*60*24));   
//> This select all teams within 1 day from last login
```

Having this number you can split all the pending you need with:

```
$pendingPerTeam = round($totalPendings / $teamWithRecentlyActivity);
```

And use this offset within my first solution

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about First option and Second options.  Maybe there is a third option.. is there a way to count total staffs have recently logged (or recent activity) and then associate them with a team? Wouldn't you think that will be better solution? I have used PHP $_SESSION when user have logged in.

Comment: If i get what you mean you just need to use the first solution and instead to divide by 2 you divide by the number of team recently logged. It's a pretty easy edit to my first solution if you want I add some code up there

Comment: Yes please, that would be great! How to get recent team recently logged or activity and then count? I guess in the member table I need something like tbl_member.activity_date = ""

Comment: man I expanded my answer. I don't know but I think I deserve at least a +1 and the pick answer XD

Comment: Thank you very much and thanks for taking your time :) I have picked your answer :) Just to clarify... I want $pendingPerTeam to calculate for two teams only. Maximum number of teams is 2

Comment: it will works with any numbers.. If in the table teams there are max 2 teams with a recently activity then the max count(*) will be 2

Comment: "SELECT count(*) FROM `team`" wouldn't show number of teams but number of recent activity in total.. Let say $totalPendings is 30 and $teamWithRecentlyActivity is 10.. $pendingPerTeam would be 3

Comment: If you say `$teamWithRecentlyActivity is 10` this means in your team table there can be up to 10 teams. But you said your max team number is 2. If your max team number is 2 then in the `team` table there are max 2 records. And if there are only 2 records the `SELECT COUNT(*)` can return only up to 2. Different is the situation if you have the table that records all teams actions (and not only the login) but at that point you only need to do a `SELECT DISTINCT`